# Why is my event handler still being triggered multiple times even though I unsubscribed from the event?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, delegates, event-handling

I have a consumer class that has a method that gets from a buffer, getFromBuffer(). The buffer is another class.  So every time something is written to the buffer I call the getFromBuffer method in the consumer class; thus I use event handlers.

```
class Buffer
{
      public delegate void GetFromBufferEvent();
      public static event GetFromBufferEvent getFromBuffer;
      string []buffer = new string[size]

      setBuffer()
      {
        //everytime something is written to the buffer
        getFromBuffer()
      }

}



class Consumer
{
      Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
      // Constructor
      Consumer(Buffer buffer)
      {
        Buffer.getFromBuffer -= new Buffer.GetFromBufferEvent(this.getFromBuffer);
        Buffer.getFromBuffer += new Buffer.GetFromBufferEvent(this.getFromBuffer);

        this.buffer = buffer;
      }

      ConsumerThread()
      {
        // continuously performs some events that trigger setBuffer in Buffer class
       // which in turn triggers getFromBuffer method in consumer class

      }

      getFromBuffer()
      {
       Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "consumed" + string)
      }
}


Main
{
      Buffer buffer = new Buffer();

      // Pass the same buffer because they need to write to the same buffer
      Consumer c1 = new Consumer(buffer);
      Consumer c2 = new Consumer(buffer);

      Thread t1 = new(ThreadStart(c1.ConsumerThread));
      Thread t2 = new(ThreadStart(c2.ConsumerThread));

      t1.Name = ("C1");
      t2.Name = ("C2");

      t1.Start();
      t2.Start();


}
```

So basically sometimes like every couple of calls it will print Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "consumed" + string twice in a row. I think the problem is that the two threads have no way of knowing if the other has subscribed or not. Since they're 2 separate threads it's not like I can set some flag because the flag won't be shared between them. How can I solve my issue? (All other functionality is 100% working, the problem stems from event subscription and unsubscription) Please help!

Oh and I have tried unsubscribing within the getFromBuffer()

Comment: `public static event GetFromBufferEvent getFromBuffer;` i sense problem with this being `static` in multithreaded scenario

Comment: Oh wait no it has to be static in order for me to reference it from consumer class

Comment: why you cannot you subscribe to instance of buffer ? like in below next comment.

Comment: `Consumer(Buffer buffer)
      {
        buffer.getFromBuffer -= new GetFromBufferEvent(this.getFromBuffer);
        buffer.getFromBuffer += new GetFromBufferEvent(this.getFromBuffer);

        this.buffer = buffer;
      }`

Comment: As another comment not sure if you should be unsubscribing from the event on a class level delegate as may cause undesirable results.

Comment: You cannot unsubscribe **other** instances of your event handler function by calling **this**.getFromBuffer as the argument. You need to use a class reference, for example passing in the old Consumer and unsubscribing it `-= oldConsumer.getFromBuffer;` By the way, `EventHandler` is the delegate you should be using and no need to use the `new` keyword.

Comment: I did do it at the class level originally, but still not behaving how I expected